# How can i display the Job name of a Jenkins freestyle Job?

Tags: jenkins

I want to be able to get the name of the running job in Jenkins inPowershell. I want to get the value and concatenate it to a string for example if the Job name is TestJob and I get the correct value I want to be able to create something like

```
 "c:\myjobs\<thejobnamevalue>\dev\app.sln"
```

I have tried the following in the batch command

```
WRITE-OUTPUT ${env.JOB_NAME}
WRITE-OUTPUT ${JOB_NAME}
```

But none prints out the job name, it just prints     echo ${env.JOB_NAME} or   echo ${JOB_NAME}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`JOB_NAME` is the correct variable that holds the name of the job, so I think the problem is the way that you are trying to reference it.

If you are running the above command in an "Execute Windows batch command" box, then you would need to write it in batch format, not powershell format. This means it should be:

```
echo %JOB_NAME%
```

If you were running a shell command, it would be:

```
echo $JOB_NAME
```

`WRITE-OUTPUT $JOB_NAME` is the correct way to reference the variable if you were running a PowerShell script, but in this case you are likely trying to run a PowerShell command in a batch environment.